# as many as have ever been

Tags: comparisons

There seem now to be **as many** tribes, and **as much** conflict between them, **as there have ever been.**

-> Would it be safe to say that this **as ~ as have ever been** structure is used to make a statement that there haven't been as many tribes as well as the conflicts among them as there are right now in the course of our history? (used like a superlative)

Comment: Note that ***as many*** is an inherently ***plural*** [count] usage, whereas ***as much*** is a ***singular*** [uncountable] form. So it's *There **are** as many tribes as there **have** ever been* and *There **is** as much conflict as there **has** ever been*. When ***both*** referents are used in the same utterance, it's normal in English to have the verb form agree with the ***second*** one ( the "plurality" of the verb should agree with the ***immediately-preceding noun phrase***, if there are multiple nouns). *There are as many tribes and as much conflict as there **has** ever been.*

Comment: 'There seem now to be as many tribes as there have ever been, and there seems to be as much conflict between them as there has ever been' is incontrovertibly correct. But ponderous. I'm actually not sure about the acceptability of your deleted form, Nor would I know where to look.

Comment: Note also that the equative construction _as ... as ..._ is a negative trigger (like comparative and superlative constructions), licensing the NPI _ever_ in the baseline proposition (_as there ever has been_). This is a very complex construction.

Answer (score 1):

The statement being made is that there have never at any time in the past been any **more** tribes than there are now, or more conflict between them.